# How to interpret Pythone memory usage with guppy?

Tags: python, memory-management, guppy

I am using code for spectral estimation of geophysical time series.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
import numpy as np
from mtspec import mtspec
from mtspec.util import _load_mtdata

from guppy import hpy
h = hpy()
print h.heap()

data = np.loadtxt('500.dat')

spec,freq,jackknife,f_statistics,degrees_of_f = mtspec(data=data, delta= 40.0, time_bandwidth=4 ,number_of_tapers=7, nfft= 512, statistics=True)
```

I got this:

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ python mt4.py 
Partition of a set of 214843 objects. Total size = 35303944 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  15461   7  8538896  24   8538896  24 unicode
     1  77241  36  7769768  22  16308664  46 str
     2  43700  20  3870600  11  20179264  57 tuple
     3    582   0  1443984   4  21623248  61 dict of PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType
     4    352   0  1395712   4  23018960  65 dict of module
     5  10118   5  1295104   4  24314064  69 types.CodeType
     6    858   0  1265136   4  25579200  72 dict (no owner)
     7   9893   5  1187160   3  26766360  76 function
     8   1123   1  1112392   3  27878752  79 dict of type
     9   1123   1  1012552   3  28891304  82 type
<900 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

If I take time series with 1000points(500 was in previous case),I got the same:

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ python mt5.py
Partition of a set of 214843 objects. Total size = 35303944 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  15461   7  8538896  24   8538896  24 unicode
     1  77241  36  7769768  22  16308664  46 str
     2  43700  20  3870600  11  20179264  57 tuple
     3    582   0  1443984   4  21623248  61 dict of PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType
     4    352   0  1395712   4  23018960  65 dict of module
     5  10118   5  1295104   4  24314064  69 types.CodeType
     6    858   0  1265136   4  25579200  72 dict (no owner)
     7   9893   5  1187160   3  26766360  76 function
     8   1123   1  1112392   3  27878752  79 dict of type
     9   1123   1  1012552   3  28891304  82 type
<900 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

So it means that doubling the time series nothing(that I can see) changes.How to interpret this?Is `guppy` right choice for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really old question, but might as well throw this out there...

you are doing the memory analysis before loading the file -- if you move `print h.heap()` after the call to `np.loadtxt(...)`, I imagine it will incorporate the data you want